# How to upgrade the Ultralite db with an existing database in android?

Tags: android, ultralite

In my application , I am using ultralite db . I have made some changes in schema of the database now my app is in already market . When user upgrade the application with new version database is not updating.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "Alter table" statement to modify existing tables and create table to add any new tables.

See,
http://dcx.sap.com/index.html#sa160/en/uladmin/ul-alter-table-statement.html

You do need to detect whether a schema change needs to applied by querying the syscolumn and systable tables.
http://dcx.sap.com/index.html#sa160/en/uladmin/fo-db-internals-s-3513569-java.html